# Node promise-io - why crash?

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm working my way through the [Node Beginner Tutorial](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) while tailoring things to work with my development style. For example I'm selecting to use coffeescript, and requirejs. The later involves a great deal of callback-soup on top of the significant regular amount. Usually these are situations I like to deal with using promises. After some minimal research [promise-io](https://github.com/kriszyp/promised-io) seems like a reasonable solution.  It works but suddenly I'm running into a problem combining promises using all (which seems analagous to jQuery.when - where this is a technique I use frequently).

The following is my server.coffee file. As is it works perfectly, replacing the nested deferreds with the `all` call serves one request then hangs the server. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

```
exports.start = ->
    requirejs ['http', 'url', './route'], (http, url, route)->
        console.log "Starting server"
        server = http.createServer (request, response) ->
            pathdata = url.parse request.url

            ###
            #this breaks
            promise.all(readingPost(request), route.promise).then (x) ->
                [postData, route] = x
                route pathdata, response, postData
            ###
            #this works
            readingPost(request).then (postData) -> route.promise.then (route) ->
                route pathdata, response, postData

        server.listen 8888

readingPost = (request) ->
    request.setEncoding 'utf-8'
    data = ''
    request.addListener 'data', (dataChunk) ->
        data += dataChunk
    d = promise.Deferred()
    request.addListener 'end', -> d.resolve data
    d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, your first example will overwrite the `route` that you loaded with `requirejs`, so the second time it runs, you will have totally different value.

Try changing

```
[postData, route] = x
route pathdata, response, postData
```

to

```
[postData, routeCb] = x
routeCb pathdata, response, postData
```

Comment: Oh you are absolutely correct! I've got to figure out how to export a single value directly rather than via properties.